# rvest error: "Error in class(out) <- "XMLNodeSet" : attempt to set an attribute on NULL"

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I'm trying to scrape a set of web pages with the new rvest package.  It works for most of the web pages but when there are no tabular entries for a particular letter, an error is returned.

```
# install the packages you need, as appropriate
install.packages("devtools")
library(devtools)
install_github("hadley/rvest")
library(rvest)
```

This code works OK because there are entries for the letter E on the web page.

```
# works OK
url <- "https://www.propertytaxcard.com/ShopHillsborough/participants/alph/E"
pg <- html_session(url, user_agent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0"))
pg %>% html_nodes(".sponsor-info .bold") %>% html_text()
```

This doesn't work because there are no entries for the letter F on the web page.  The error message is  "Error in class(out) <- "XMLNodeSet" : attempt to set an attribute on NULL"

```
# yields error message
url <- "https://www.propertytaxcard.com/ShopHillsborough/participants/alph/F"
pg <- html_session(url, user_agent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0"))   
pg %>% html_nodes(".sponsor-info .bold") %>% html_text()
```

Any suggestions. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could always wrap the `pg`…`html_nodes`…`html_text` in `try` and test for the class afterwards:

```
tmp <- try(pg %>% html_nodes(".sponsor-info .bold") %>% html_text(), silent=TRUE)

if (class(tmp) == "character") {
  print("do stuff")
} else {
  print("do other stuff")
}
```

EDIT: one other option is to use the `boolean()` XPath operator and do the test that way:

```
html_nodes_exist <- function(rvest_session, xpath) {

  xpathApply(content(rvest_session$response, as="parsed"), 
             sprintf("boolean(%s)", xpath))

}

pg %>% html_nodes_exist("//td[@class='sponsor-info']/span[@class='bold']")
```

which will return `TRUE` if those nodes exist and `FALSE` if they don't (that function needs to be generalized to be able to use `session` and `["HTMLInternalDocument" "HTMLInternalDocument" "XMLInternalDocument"  "XMLAbstractDocument"]` objects and work with both CSS selectors as well as XPath, but it's a way to avoid `try`.

Comment: FYI the latest version of `xml2` has newer ways to deal with this. I'll post an update tomorrowish.